# 32 bit Qt program can't find Qt Postgres plugin dll on 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, postgresql-9.1, mingw32

I have a 32 bit program built with mingw which uses Qt's QSqlDatabase class to access a Postgres database.  We install the program to c:\company\product\bin. We place the Qt PSQL driver plugin, qsqlpsql4.dll, in C:\company\product\bin\sqldrivers.

It works fine on 32 bit Windows 7 or 32 bit windows XP. When run on 64 bit Windows 7, I get this output:

> QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
>   QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC
>
> Failed to open database connection. Invalid driver specfied.

It refuses to find the QPSQL driver. I've tried using a qt.conf file to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm missing?

Comment: Is libpq.dll in PATH? and libpq's other dependencies like libeay,  libiconv, libintl, ssleay?

Comment: Hmmm, Dependency Walker shows that libpq.dll is found, but a 64 bit version. That would be an issue. It's also reporting 64 bit versions found of several system DLLs. I'll try installing 32 bit postgres.

Comment: where do you get libpq.dll from? postgresql website? If I'm correct by assuming you're doing client server app, why would you need to install a db server on your client computers just to get libpq.dll? can't you just provide it and its dependencies along with your binary app?

Comment: libpq.dll comes from the postgres installation. Our program will always (for the moment) be run on the same server where the database is installed.

Comment: To connect PostgreSQL one doesn't need specific libpq.dll, but for an app linked against a dll (any, if it matters) it will be hard to know what will break if one uses same version of a dll compiled by different compiler, let alone different versions of the same dll. So IMHO you can ship any version of PostgreSQL server along with your app, but also ship a version of libpq.dll that your app last known to work with. Better yet, compile your own along with your app.

Comment: In my case it was the other way around - dev in win 7 64 bit, I compiled libpq.dll myself(32-bit) and deploy it to win XP 32 bit. No problems whatsoever.